Low Server Storage workaround for indexing a website with wget
I am runing wget, indexing a big website (may be more than 30 GB)  in my VPS which has got small storage (5GB free storage), so I am using a parallel script to empty the contents of this index periodically (as soon as the VPS is below certain GB of free storage it will trigger an rsync command). This is been sent to my homeServer which has got plenty of storage.
These are examples of the 2 scripts
    wget \
    `## Recursive Retrieval Options` \
      --recursive --level=4 \
    `## Recursive Accept/Reject Options` \
      --no-parent \
    https://awebiste.com

Then alongside in other terminal I run the following
check_disk_space() {
    if [ $(df | awk '$1 == "/dev/vda1" {print $4}') -gt 6291456 ]; then
        echo "There is enough space."
    else
        echo "Moving chunk of files to remote drive on ${remote_ip} freeing up space on VPS"
        rsync -av --remove-source-files ${DOCU_PATH}/downloaded/ ${remote_ip}:${DST_PATH}/downloaded/
        rsync -av ${DOCU_PATH}/downloaded/ ${remote_ip}:${DST_PATH}/downloaded/
    fi
}
# Endless loop
while true; do
    check_disk_space  # Call the function
    sleep 300  # Sleep for 300 seconds (5 minutes)
done


The lastone will be checking the space of the device and dump the files to my homeServer
The issue is that my home connection is not pretty stable, and while this sometimes runs good , if the index of the website runs faster than the dumping process to my homeServer , myVps will run out of storage and will finnish the index process of wget with a
Cannot write to /my/path/tofile (No space left on device).

I was wondering if there is a way to script this, ideally to tell wget not to exit automatically but wait for a User Prompt to resume it or finnish it.
Or to make it trigger this dumping command.
Eitherways , it looks like the problem is complex, as once wget throw that error, it has already exited , with an exit status of 3 which means File I/O Error
So I cannot handle the issue by tackling the exit status, I need the space dumper script to send a certain signal to the wget process , to pause it , waiting until there is enough space left to resume again that process , so I guess handling this via signals.
So I have delved into Signals a bit then and could be STOPPING and CONTinouing the process by doing
kill -s STOP <PID>
kill -s CONT <PID>

I haven't used it yet , but thinking about Stopping wget from outside doesnt look to be a good idea, as you can find the wget process on the middle of a http request download process , and if halted and resumed, the server may not handle it correctly , (plust wget process may not handle it too). (though wget has --continue may handle this well)
I am about to code something on this way.
Has anyone have any ideas about this?

This is not a sane approach. Spin up a an instance in some cloud; you pay per hour, so cost will be quite low. And it's not about managing business IT.
